# How can i kill distributed worker in Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am working with Apache Kafka and using distributed worker. I can start my worker as below:

```
// Command to start the distributed worker.
"bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties"
```

This is from official documentation. After this we can create connectors and tasks. And this works fine.

But when i change my connector or task logic I should add new `jar` to classpath of kafka. And after this I should restart worker.

I don't know how it should be right I think we should stop and run worker.

But when I want to stop worker I don't know how i can do it correctly.
    ofcourse, I can find my process by `ps aux | grep worker`, kill it and kill rest server which i should find by `ps` too. But i think it's strange case. Killing two processes isn't good idea, but i can't find any information how we can do it in another way.

If you know right way, please help me:)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is a shell script to stop the rest server in confluent newer versions. Please check "kafka-rest-stop.sh" for stopping rest server. But no script is available for stopping worker. Even I am stopping by killing the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Killing two processes isn't good idea

`ConnectDistributed` is only **one** process. There is no separate REST server to stop.

And yes, `:connector/pause` followed by a `kill <pid>` is the correct way to stop it.

If installed with a recent version of Confluent Platform, you can stop/start using `systemctl`.